# I have a problem importing a Bit compiler. How can I resolve the following error?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, ssh, bit

I'm working with 'Bit' to create reusable React components. I have created my 'Bit' account and followed tutorials on the web to log on to Bit from the terminal and I have initialized the Bit workspace. I am encountering the following error when importing the React compiler.

$ bit import bit.envs/compilers/react --compiler

fatal: unable to connect to a remote legacy SSH server from Harmony client

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of Bit are you using? If it is 15 (Harmony), then you can have your workspace ready for React development with this command: bit new react <my-workspace-name>

Answer (score 0):

the `compiler` flag was removed in 0.0.537

harmony became default in 0.0.438 (so legacy was last default in 0.0.437)

but ... if you try to run this on 0.0.437 now, you're likely to get an error:

```
server responded with: "Please update your Bit client.
For additional information: https://docs.bit.dev/docs/installation#latest-version"
```

the best place to get bit.dev answers is their community Slack here: https://join.slack.com/t/bit-dev-community/shared_invite/zt-o2tim18y-UzwOCFdTafmFKEqm2tXE4w.